# Haskell XML pull parser

Tags: haskell, xml-parsing

Is there an XML pull parser (similar to Java StAX) for Haskell?

I am envisioning using it with a pure function that accepts a parser. My function will call something like `nextItem parser` and pattern-match on the result (`StartElement`, `EndElement`, `Text`, `EntityRef`, etc.) My function can then call itself recursively to process child elements, etc., constructing a private data structure as it traverses the XML "tree".

As I understand it, pull-parsing should have better performance than constructing an internal representation of the DOM, then traversing it, although I don't know if this is true in a lazy language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [xml-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit), which provides both streaming and full-document modules. The streaming parsing module [Text.XML.Stream.Parse](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xml-conduit/1.0.3.3/doc/html/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html) also provides a number of helper combinators.

It's true that if you had a truly lazy data source, there would be no (significant) performance difference between a pull parser and dealing with the lazy list. However, XML parsing usually involves I/O. conduit is designed to give you a high-level approach to these kinds of parsing issues.

Comment: I'll check it out (Appendix F in your book).